# cacheAsBitmap not working on different stageSizes?

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel-perfect

I'm loading a MovieClip which pixels should be displayed perfectly.
Every child of this MovieClip and the MovieClip itself uses only whole integers in position and size.
The funny thing is that even if I use "myMovieClip.cacheAsBitmap = true" sometimes it will appear blurry.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that all of the x/y positions are whole integers as well!

If you have x = 0.5, the MC will appear blurry, and the the cacheAsBitmap function will store the image as blurry :)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that strokes can straddle the pixels, giving you fractional pixels even if the numbers look right.  For example, if you have a 3px stroke on a rectangle that is positioned at 5, 5, the outer edge of the stroke will actually be at 3.5, 3.5, and the inner edge will be at 6.5, 6.5.